# Use socket.io in resolve to realise one-time listeners

Tags: javascript, socket.io, promise, angular-ui-router, q

I used to put one-time listeners inside `resolve`. The following code can make sure that the page must receive a message `yes` to resolve `x`, then "yes again" to resolve `y`, etc:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('edit', {
            resolve: {
                x: ['$q', function ($q) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
                        if (e.data === "yes") deferred.resolve(e.data)
                    }, { once: true };
                    return deferred.promise
                }],
                y: ... ...
                        if (e.data === "yes again") deferred.resolve(e.data)
                   ... ...
                    return deferred.promise
                }],
                z: ... ...
                    return deferred.promise
```

Now I want to use `socket.io` to realise the listener; it listens to the messages emitted by the server. If it was not in a `resolve`, I would use the following to receive messages:

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('message', function (message) {
   console.log(message)
})
```

I need to get one `socket` for one page. Does anyone know how to put it into several `resolve` to achieve what the event listeners did?

Comment: `several resolve` - sounds like you want to resolve a promise more than once

Comment: I mean resolving a promise, then resolving another promise, then resolving another promise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following code `socket.once` to imitate one-time listener, it works without errors so far:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('edit', {
            resolve: {
                socket: [function () {
                    return io.connect();
                }],
                x: ['socket', '$q', function (socket, $q) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    socket.once("message", function (msg) {
                        if (msg.req === "yes") deferred.resolve(msg)
                    })
                    return deferred.promise
                }],
                y: ... ...
                        if (msg.req === "yes again") deferred.resolve(msg)
                   ... ...
                    return deferred.promise
                }],
                z: ... ...
                    return deferred.promise
```

Comment: What happens when `msg.req !== "yes"`?

Comment: From my understanding of `socket.once`, if `msg.req !== "yes"`, `deferred` will never be resolved, so the code will hang forever. It is OK for me, because I know the order of the messages, I just need to make sure all the messages are caught. I guess (I have not tried), if I use `socket.on` rather than `socket.once`, a block will move on once it receives a `msg` such that `msg.req === "yes"`, `msg` is not necessarily the first message a block receives... Hopefully `socket.on` of different blocks will not interfere among them...

Comment: I think the best way is to, for each block, add a listener by `socket.on`, remove the listener once `msg.req` is correct, and move on... But I don't know how to remove the listener itself inside a listener function...

Comment: If you're using the same socket.io message name in different blocks, you can't guarantee which message belongs to which promise and that is a reliability problem.  This design still seems very troublesome to me without even seeing the larger picture of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Event listeners do not align well with promises because promises are one-shot devices, yet event listeners can be called many times.  So, if you create a promise for an event, it will be called only once and any events that occur after that first one will be ignored.

It would be possible to create some sort of interface where you got a series of promises with the first one resolved with the first event trigger, the second promise with the second one and so on, but you'd have to call a function to get the next promise in order to have some code that makes new promises and has a caller to return it to (which would likely end up feeling like a hack to use).  It is probably just simpler to use a regular callback for each event trigger and if you then want to carry out some further asynchronous operation based on the event trigger, you create a promise at that point to help you manage the further activities.

**Promises are just not an appropriate architectural match for recurring events.**  Promises are one-shot devices so they should be used to represent a one-shot happening.  Open a file, get a promise back that resolves when that file is now open.  Make a specific http request and get a promise back that resolves with the response from the request.

Comment: Thank you for your comment... I successfully used `socket.once` to imitate one-time listener (see my answer), with promises this solution does not change too much the initial structure of my code...